# How to read from text file in Map specific data?

Tags: java, file, dictionary

I need the read from the data file of the form:

1,14.23,1.71,2.43,15.6,127,2.8,3.06,.28,2.29,5.64,1.04,3.92,1065
2,12.72,1.81,2.2,18.8,86,2.2,2.53,.26,1.77,3.9,1.16,3.14,714
2,12.08,1.13,2.51,24,78,2,1.58,.4,1.4,2.2,1.31,2.72,630
....................................
3,13.11,1.9,2.75,25.5,116,2.2,1.28,.26,1.56,7.1,.61,1.33,425
3,13.23,3.3,2.28,18.5,98,1.8,.83,.61,1.87,10.52,.56,1.51,675
................and so on

Where first symbol - the key, the rest are values.

I try to do it this way

```
 Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("wine.data.txt"));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                String parts[] = line.split(",");
                for(int i = 1; i < parts.length; i++)
                map.put(parts[0], parts[i]);
                System.out.println(map.toString());
            }
            in.close();
```

But I see only last number of each line.
How to fix it?

Comment: `map.put(parts[0], parts[i])` puts always the same key in your map, since `parts[0]` never changes in your loop, so you get exactly one entry in your map after all.

Comment: @MadMatts: `parts` is the same throughout each *for* loop; it changes with each iteration of the enclosing *while* loop.

Comment: yes, you're right, sry I overlooked that...

Answer (score 1):

Everytime `put` is called, the value for the speficied key is being replaced.

You want to store the result in a `Map<String, List<String>>`:

```
String parts[] = line.split(",");
List<String> values = map.get(parts[0]);
if(values == null) {   // first time this key is found -> create new list
    values = new ArrayList<>();
    map.put(parts[0], values);
}
for(int i = 1; i < parts.length; i++) {
    values.add(parts[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`map` associates each key with a string; each time you call `put`, you *replace* whatever string used to be associated with that key.

It isn't clear what you want the outcome to be, so I can't say how to fix it.

Comment: Maybe you can suggest me better structure for this task?

Comment: Maybe you can say what the task is?  For the example input data, what do you *want* `map` to end up containing?

Comment: I need to read numbers from file and work with them on. To end up in Collection must be all numbers as key and value(you can see description above).

Answer (score 0):

Your code will overwrite the value in each iteration and will give the last value as final one. 
Instead use a list, add all the values there, and assign that list as map value.

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("wine.data.txt"));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                String parts[] = line.split(",");
                ArrayList<String> arrList = new ArrayList<String>();
                for(int i = 1; i < parts.length; i++)
                    arrList.add(parts[i]);
                map.put(parts[0], arrList);
                System.out.println(map.toString());
            }
            in.close();
```

Try this. It should work fine.

Comment: Thank you, it most closely, but now I see the last LINE, of each key/

Comment: What do you actually want to do with the values? Please mention, then better solution can be suggested.

Comment: I must procecced every line from this big file (mathematical operation)

Comment: your question is vague, not clear. Can you please tell what operation you want to perform on that?

Comment: for instance : despention, average module deviations, median and so on

Answer (score 0):

Issue is that you were using same key to store each record in row. Its necessary to do a little fundamental change by using List instead of String as value in map. By the end you will get all items in each row as itemList with its own key(1st record). Here is the implementation based on your code:

```
Map<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("wine.data.txt"));
String line = "";
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
      String parts[] = line.split(",");
      ArrayList<String> valueList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(parts));
      valueList.remove(0);// get rid of 1st element because it will be used as akey
      map.put(parts[0], valueList);
      System.out.println(map.toString());
}
in.close();
```